# List multiprocessing in groovy

Tags: groovy, gpars

I have a list of URLs in groovy for which I would like to start a new thread for each. I would like to know the groovy way of doing this list multiprocessing.
Suppose I have a list of urls I wish to fetch data from concurrently.

```
def urls = ["https://stackexchange.com","https://amazon.com","https://bing.com","https://google.com"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

def urls = ["https://stackexchange.com","https://amazon.com","https://bing.com","https://google.com"]

GParsPool.withPool( urls.size() ) { urls.eachParallel { url ->
try {
        // test if url is reachable
        response = url.toURL().text
        println url + " connected OK"
    } 
catch (Exception e) {  println e }
    }
}
```

Comment: `withPool( urls.size() )` must reflect a number of cores and not the list size

Comment: Probably best to go with the default, and just do `withPool {`

Comment: @injecteer No that's not true. Where did you read this? I created a demo script last night. It tests connectivity to 1200 servers. Try lowering the pool size to your core count and it will take much longer to complete. https://github.com/irthomasthomas/groovyproxies

Comment: @tim_yates I published a little test script https://github.com/irthomasthomas/groovyproxies if I alter it to use just withPool {, it takes 30x longer.

Comment: I guess the assumption for the default ([nProcessors + 1](https://github.com/GPars/GPars/blob/master/src/main/groovy/groovyx/gpars/util/PoolUtils.java#L42)) is that the things in the pool are going to be doing a lot of processing, wheras in this case, we're probably spending a lot of time blocked waiting for a connection to be resolved and made to the server.

Comment: @tim_yates Exactly, it's an IO bound task so we want to use a thread per each request.

Comment: Using "tasks" amount threads because it's IO bound, ignores completly the other end. Especially if you query sites outside of your controll.  All answering at once can overwhelm your end or they might just tarpit/blacklist you for your behaviour.

Comment: @cfrick We didn't ignore the other-end, the other end is deigned for high throughput, and can easily handle this. I'm not going to overwelm them here. Use the tool you need for the job.

Comment: @Brian although it's tempting to write "just a little script" to check the connectivity of these servers: if you're trying to implement some kind of monitoring, then there are better ways (e.g. Nagios)